# $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading of a vector space by an involution

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, involutions

Assume we have a complex vector space $V$ and an involution $\omega:V\to V$, that is $\omega²=id$.

Does this give a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading of $V$ somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$-grading is a spitting $V \cong V_0 \oplus V_1$. $V$ splits as the $1$-eigenspace and the $-1$-eigenspace with respect to $\omega$, so this give two natural gradings on $V$.

Comment: I don't understand, what is $V_0$ and $V_1$ here?

Comment: @R.A. : What is your definition of a $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$ grading ?

Comment: Just a decompisition into a direct sum with two summands. I think we agree?

Comment: Yes, so $V_0$ is the first summand and $V_1$ is the second one.

Comment: Yes, but what is $V_0$? The eigenspace of $i$?

Comment: This is why I said "two natural grading" : I think there is no prefered choice here, so you can choose $V_0$ to be either eigenspace of $i$ or the eigenspace of $-i$.

Comment: Alright, now I got it. Can we choose also the $1$ or $-1$-eigenspace?

Comment: Sorry I made a very stupid mistake, you need to replace $i$ and $-i$ by $1$ and $-1$ everywhere. I feel pretty silly, I should take a little break now ...

Comment: Ok, now we do agree :D Thank you!

Comment: I edited the answer for clarity but sorry about it again.